# how to improve forms on iOS safari using iScroll? (keyboard breaks page when it disappears)

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, iscroll, iscroll4

So when you manage to put inputs and textareas into iscroll, the iOS safari keyboard at times can cut off the bottom of the page after it hides itself. Has anyone found any good fixes for this?

Comment: A screenshot would be helpful. Is the area under the keyboard not being restored?

Comment: Exactly. I'll add a screenshot when I'm back at my computer (on the phone now).

Comment: This is mainly an iOS 6 issue. Ios7 responds by iscroll being stuck above the viewport.

Comment: Also, it sometimes happen in ios6 with no iscroll but a lot less. I'm thinking their must be some precise CSS that should be used instead that make repaints easier.